# How to validated input type text with numeric in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a input box which is of type text, i wanted only to enter the numbers and it should not exceed max length of 6 in react. please give some reference on it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex and a simple `.length` validation. Here's an example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { number: '' };
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    const val = e.target.value;
    if (val.length <= 6 && /^(\s*|\d+)$/.test(val)) {
      this.setState({
        number: val
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.number} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="View"></div>
```

You could also go with the HTML5 validation, but it only checks when being submitted:

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" max="999999" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.